# How to get all executed SQL queries in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is possible to find out all SQL queries and their return code, which was executed in Oracle database? Specially I want to get all sql queries which has negative sql code (error).

Thank you for answer.

Comment: This question seems to ask about auditing, but it's the first time I hear the concept of *negative SQL* `:-?`

Comment: SQL code with a goatee? [/classic Star Trek]

Comment: @Alvaro `sqlcode` is the status value of an executed statement in Oracle.

Comment: That's so broad a question that it is almost impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @rejj in v$sql are sql commands, but I don't know if this sql was succesfull or not

Answer (score 2):

Everything which was executed?  That would require enabling [auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/auditing.htm#i1011984), and fine-grained auditing to boot - and auditing every statement in a database can generate a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can execute your queries within a (anonymous) PL/SQL block, and then use the its *exception handler* to catch "negative" statements:

```
begin
  insert into a values (1, 4/0);
exception when others then
  ... error has happened,
  ... use 'sqlerrm' and 'sqlcode' 
  ... for further analysis
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is way, but we have around 2000 PL/SQL blocks and I really dont want write it for each procedure/function/trigger

Answer (score -1):

if you want any solution of error code than please check out Oracle docs for Error message pdf, in which you were find out various error code with its description....